# array with keys - node

Tags: javascript, server, client

Hello I have basic problem...

```
    socket.on('addPlayer', function(){

    socket.player = {
        id: server.lastPlayderID++,
        x: randomInt(100,400),
        y: randomInt(100,400)           
    }
    players[socket.id] = socket.player;
    console.log(players);
    socket.emit('allplayers', players);

});

Client.socket.on('allplayers',function(data){
console.log(data);});
```

my allplayers says that data is empty even if players[] are not empty and server console.log shows content of players.

Comment: personally, I'd make players an object rather than an array - though, I can't see where the players var is declared, so ...

Comment: I have declared it globally - var players = [];